# why sshd have 2 processes per client?

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh

I am setting up a VPS server, and I have an habit of running `pstree -p` on it. I just noticed that sshd seems to have only 1 server process initially, then adds 2 more for each client connection on that system (it's a debian buster running runit-init, sshd script being written by me).
Adding 1 more instance per connection makes a lot of sense to me, but why 2?

Here is a `pstree -p` result showing that:

```
runit(1)-+-runsvdir(1303)-+-runsv(1341)-+-busybox(1366)
         |                |             `-svlogd(1365)
         |                |-runsv(1342)-+-sshd(1361)-+-sshd(16288)---sshd(16294)---bash(16295)
         |                |             |            `-sshd(16305)---sshd(16311)---bash(16312)---pstree(16319)
         |                |             `-svlogd(1360)
         |                |-runsv(1343)---getty(1354)
         |                |-runsv(1344)---getty(1353)
         |                |-runsv(1345)---getty(1352)
         |                |-runsv(1346)---getty(1351)
         |                |-runsv(1347)---getty(1349)
         |                |-runsv(1348)---getty(1350)
         |                `-runsv(13966)---runsvdir(14047)---runsv(14048)-+-darkhttpd(15417)
         |                                                                `-svlogd(15291)
         `-systemd-udevd(442)
```

And here is my sshd run script:

```sh
. /etc/runit/common
test -e /run/sshd || mkdir /run/sshd
exec /usr/sbin/sshd -D -e
```

The content of `/etc/runit/common` (only for completeness, it's pretty empty, but I intend to add stuff there later):

```sh
exec 2>&1
set -xe
```

I have no abnormal behavior (and I know stuff are perfectible, to), I am just curious about the why of the   thing.

Answer (score 4):

The question is a cross-site duplicate of [*Why does `sshd` (OpenSSH) create two processes per connection?*](https://serverfault.com/q/585781) The [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/585782):

> Privilege separation - one process that retains root privileges to do things that only root can do, and another that does everything else.
>
> […]

To confirm run `pstree -u`.

<sup>(`-u`: show uid transitions;  whenever the uid of a process differs from the uid of its parent, the new uid is shown in parentheses after the process name).</sup>